# tika solr integration

Tags: solr, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

I am trying to index using curl based request

the request is

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr1/update/extract?literal.id=who.pdf&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true" -F "myfile=@/root/apache-solr-3.1.0/docs/who.pdf"
```

On submitting the request, i am getting this error,

```
 Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - ERROR:unknown field 'ignored_meta'</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>ERROR:unknown field 'ignored_meta'</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (ERROR:unknown field 'ignored_meta').</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.18</h3></body></html>r
```

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is due to the fact that the default handler for ExtractingRequestHandler defined in the solrconfig.xml put all the Tika's not identified extracted fields into fields named 'ingored_XXXXX'.

To solve this, you can simply add to your Solr configuration a field name 'ignored_*' like this:

```
<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored"/>
```

Don't forget to add also the ignored type if you remove it from the default configuration:

```
<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />
```

This will stop your Solr from crashing when Tika index fields that Solr don't know of.

Comment: thanks i did the same thing .. i forgot to put dynamic field ... it was exactly same what you mentioned .. and good thing about that now we are getting very good result after integrating with tika .. thanks jens